# Use Type class to call parameterized constructor

Tags: apex, type, constructor

Using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/) to get below working:

```
    public class t12345 implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

        String query;
        Boolean xyz;

        public t12345(String query){
            this.query= query;
        }

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bC){      
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
    }
```

and when I run below from developer console,

```
    Type api = Type.forName('t12345');
    Object apiCall = JSON.deserialize('{"query":"hello world"}',api);
Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>) apiCall);
```

above execution results in error `Argument 1 cannot be null` which is coming from start method of batch where query value is still null as constructor with query is not invoked

Comment: You should include your error message verbatim if you have one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(); // or any other approach to construction
Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<Account>)instance);
```

You should get this error:

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type MyClass to Database.Batchable

If you want to cast a class to `Database.Batchable<SObject>`, it has to implement that interface.

Instead of:

```
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Use:

```
public class MyClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject> { ... }
```

This adjustment will mean you actually have to define the methods enforced by that interface.

Comment: Thansk Adrian. I am preparing object in t12345 which is calling batch class that uses batchable interface. I corrected my question accordingly. Goal is to call parameterized constructor in batch class. I tried to generalize my error. sorry for any confusuion

Answer (score 4):

You cannot generically call a non-no-argument constructor. While other object-oriented languages have methods for doing this, Apex Code does not have any support for this.

Answer (score 3):

Your `JSON.deserialize` will (probably) set the fields but not via the constructor you have the `System.debug` in. (Constructors can have an arbitrary signature but the field names are effectively a fixed signature.)

Comment: I am trying to call batch using that object return type. Updated question above.