# Call Parametrized constructor using Type.newInstance()?

Tags: apex, inheritance, constructor

I am designing a solution where it should be flexible to add handlers using configuration.

So I am saving the handler class name in the custom metadata record and then would be instantiating it using Type.newInstance.

Each class I create implements Queueable and has a parametrized constructor. I cant figure out a way to call parametrized constructor. Its because newInstance doesn't accept any parameters and always calls the default constructor.

Abstract code:

```
public Class Class1 implements Queueable{

    private Id recordId;

    public class Class1(Id recordId){
        this.recordId =recordId;
    }
    //executeMethod

    }


public Class Class2 implements Queueable{

    private Id recordId;



    public class Class2(Id recordId){
        this.recordId =recordId;
    }

//executeMethod

}


//Running Code
Type t = Type.forName('Class1'); //Fetched from custom metadata

System.enqueueJob((Queueable)t.newInstance('001123123123123123')); //Compile time error
```

I stumbled upon this. [Use Type class to call parameterized constructor](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204840/use-type-class-to-call-parameterized-constructor) which is similar but different when the context is concerned.

Is there an elegant way to handle this solution in Apex?

Comment: Apex does not support full reflection as java do. May be you want to wrap your instantiation code in a method which will use default constructor to create instance and call extra methods to set params, but yes your handlers needs to start supporting some interface which will help you to set values. Adrian's solution looks good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically if you want several different types you want to dynamically instantiate, and want to support the same property being set on all of them, you can use an an `interface` or `virtual`/`abstract` class. For what you have above, that might look like:

```
abstract class HasRecordId
{
    Id recordId;
    HasRecordId setRecordId(Id input)
    {
        recordId = input;
        return this;
    }
}
class Foo implements Queueable extends HasRecordId
{
    // implementation
}
class Bar implements Queueable extends HasRecordId
{
    // implementation
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
HasRecordId job = ((HasRecordId)Type.forName('Foo')).setRecordId('...');
```